How to convert rows to columns and columns to rows in Angular
Just need your help and idea on how to convert rows to columns and columns to rows in angular.
[ {"playerId": "1001","playerName": "Lebron James","game": "Game1","score": 35}, {"playerId": "1001","playerName": "Lebron James","game": "Game2","score": 40}, {"playerId": "1001","playerName": "Lebron James","game": "Game3","score": 38}, {"playerId": "1001","playerName": "Lebron James","game": "Game4","score": 25}, {"playerId": "1002","playerName": "Anthony Davis","game": "Game1","score": 18}, {"playerId": "1002","playerName": "Anthony Davis","game": "Game2","score": 12}, {"playerId": "1002","playerName": "Anthony Davis","game": "Game3","score": 7}, {"playerId": "1002","playerName": "Anthony Davis","game": "Game4","score": 17} ]
to
[ {"playerId": "1001","playerName": "Lebron James","Game1": 35,"Game2": 40,"Game3": 38,"Game4": 25,"total": 138}, {"playerId": "1002","playerName": "Anthony Davis","Game1": 18,"Game2": 12,"Game3": 7,"Game4": 17,"total": 54} ]
and back to
[ {"playerId": "1001","playerName": "Lebron James","game": "Game1","score": 35}, {"playerId": "1001","playerName": "Lebron James","game": "Game2","score": 40}, {"playerId": "1001","playerName": "Lebron James","game": "Game3","score": 38}, {"playerId": "1001","playerName": "Lebron James","game": "Game4","score": 25}, {"playerId": "1002","playerName": "Anthony Davis","game": "Game1","score": 18}, {"playerId": "1002","playerName": "Anthony Davis","game": "Game2","score": 12}, {"playerId": "1002","playerName": "Anthony Davis","game": "Game3","score": 7}, {"playerId": "1002","playerName": "Anthony Davis","game": "Game4","score": 17} ]

Can you show your attempt(s)? Stack Overflow is not a platform that asks people to write the code without providing own effort.

I really appreciate your feedback Yong Shun, I  just joined the platform recently. The last time I checked for people in this platform who asked to write code without providing own effort are too many. So I guess I can do the same, Anyways thanks for your time.

It just makes you make an effort for your good mate, the only way we could learn and obviously no one here came without doing the same  ... Its up to you though

It is not specific to Angular but to the JavaScript ... you should know about grouping the array
My try would be something as below snippet using Array's reduce method and object's method to get the values

Make a object with the unique values and check if the value as key exists group accordingly
The object values would be the structure you would need in general ..



const data = [{
  "playerId": "1001",
  "playerName": "Lebron James",
  "game": "Game1",
  "score": 35
}, {
  "playerId": "1001",
  "playerName": "Lebron James",
  "game": "Game2",
  "score": 40
}, {
  "playerId": "1001",
  "playerName": "Lebron James",
  "game": "Game3",
  "score": 38
}, {
  "playerId": "1001",
  "playerName": "Lebron James",
  "game": "Game4",
  "score": 25
}, {
  "playerId": "1002",
  "playerName": "Anthony Davis",
  "game": "Game1",
  "score": 18
}, {
  "playerId": "1002",
  "playerName": "Anthony Davis",
  "game": "Game2",
  "score": 12
}, {
  "playerId": "1002",
  "playerName": "Anthony Davis",
  "game": "Game3",
  "score": 7
}, {
  "playerId": "1002",
  "playerName": "Anthony Davis",
  "game": "Game4",
  "score": 17
}]


const grouped = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(!(curr['playerId'] in acc)){
      acc[curr['playerId']] = {'playerName': curr.playerName, total: 0, 'playerId': curr.playerId}  
    }else{
        acc[curr['playerId']][curr['game']] = curr.score;
        acc[curr['playerId']]['total'] += curr.score;
    }
    return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(grouped))  // expected output 



